# ReactJS material-ui adding a style to an HTML tag element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a reactjs file which loads an Icon from material-ui

```
import LocalHospital from "@material-ui/icons/LocalHospital";
```

Then in another part of the page, I am using the icon inside another HTML tag

```
    <div className={classes.features}>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem md={4} sm={4}>
          <InfoArea
            title="Addressing Crucial Diseases"
            description="Thermo analyser products aiming to solve severe problems whihc have real and crucial implications on human lives."
            icon={Accessible}
            iconColor="danger"
            vertical={true}
          />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem md={4} sm={4}>
          <InfoArea
            title="Novel and Reliable Approaches"
            description="Thermo analyser employs novel and sophisticated apporches to effectively diagnose major diseases in reliable and acurate way."
            icon={<LocalHospital style={{ fill: "green" }} />}
            iconColor="transparent"
            vertical={true}
          />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem md={4} sm={4}>
          <InfoArea
            title="Effective and Accurate Results"
            description="Our products are scientifically proven softwares which have been developed by proficient experts in the field. They have achived an accuracy of at least %98 in our test use-cases."
            icon={Healing}
            iconColor="success"
            vertical={true}
          />
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
```

The problem is that I need to change the style of LocalHospital Icon in the JS file for example adig the below style to the Icon

```
style={{"fill": "green"}}
```

But I am not sure how to programmatically do it in the reactjs file?

per the comment, I edited my tags but that yet doesn't work..

```
  <InfoArea
    title="Novel and Reliable Approaches"
    description="Thermo analyser employs novel and sophisitcated apporches to effectively diagnose major diseases in reliable and acurate way."
    icon={() => <LocalHospital style={{ fill: "green" }}
    iconColor="transparent"
    vertical={true}
  />
```

It gave me below error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `InfoArea`.
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
C:/ThermoAnalyser/material-kit-pro-react-v1.9.0/src/index.js:46
  43 | 
  44 | var hist = createBrowserHistory();
  45 | 
> 46 | ReactDOM.render(
  47 |   <Router history={hist}>
  48 |     <Switch>
  49 |       <Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUsPage} />
```

Comment: So you want to pass down the style attribute from InfoArea to the local hospital? Does this help: `<InfoArea icon={() => <LocalHospital style={{ fill: "green" }} />} />` (of course you would need to add your other props like description again)

Comment: can you please help me out of this..I applied your comments but that yet doesn't work..

Comment: you should reproduce this on codesandbox so other will catch up more easily

Answer (score 0):

To change styling of icon you don't need arrow function inside, it can be done just like that

```
  <InfoArea
    title="Novel and Reliable Approaches"
    description="Thermo analyser employs novel and sophisitcated apporches to effectively diagnose major diseases in reliable and acurate way."
    icon={<LocalHospital style={{ fill: "green" }} />}
    iconColor="transparent"
    vertical={true}
  />
```

Comment: this gives me an error ..Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `InfoArea`.

Comment: I assumed it was Mui component where is can you show how InfoArea looks like?

Comment: I editted my qustion, infoarea is inside a container..

Comment: Any solution for this? I would apprecite any clue..

Comment: I mean usually the solution I wrote should work that's why I would like to somehow try to reproduce your error and it would be best if you made codesandbox for me to see exactly what is going on